# In Wordpress, how can a page display the parameter that was sent to it

Tags: wordpress, parameters

A WP page is being linked to from some posts and it appears that it can be improved by setting the posts to use a text parameter, like :

http://www.example.com/thepage?param=text1

I couldn't find how I can display this 'text1' parameter from within the page - if at all possible.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the template being used for that page. You can grab the value in the header OR in the body. If you simply want to display this value use the following code.

If you want to use it as a variable for some other purpose, assign it to a variable.

Comment: oops, my php code was removed because of php tags. 

if(isset($_GET['param'])) { echo $_GET['param']; } 

If you want to use it as a variable for some other purpose, assign it to a variable.

 if(isset($_GET['param'])) { $param = $_GET['param']; }

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to get the text1 parameter you can use

```
 if (isset($_GET['param'])) {
     // $_GET['param'] is equal to text1
     echo $_GET['param'];
 }
```